# Mac OS X 10.6/MacBook Pro: "NVRM: xxxx called in D3"

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

Greetings,

I'm having odd messages showing up in my console for a while now. Any ideas what they are about? Couldn't find something useful using Google.

```
NVRM: 7032 called in D3
NVRM: 7032 called in D3
NVRM: 7032 called in D3
NVRM: 7032 called in D3
NVRM: 7037 called in D3
NVRM: 7037 called in D3
NVRM: 7032 called in D3
NVRM: 7037 called in D3
NVRM: 7032 called in D3
NVRM: 7032 called in D3
NVRM: 7032 called in D3
NVRM: 7032 called in D3
NVRM: 7037 called in D3
NVRM: 7037 called in D3
NVRM: 7032 called in D3
```

Thanks in advance!

Basti

Comment: Do you have an NVIDIA GPU? Additionally, are you having problems around the time of these messages, or you're wondering if it's something to be concerned about?

Comment: My MacBook generally has a few issues (DVD drive hardly works, sometimes won't wake up from sleep, disk starting to throw errors). Except for that I'm not having big issues when these messages appear. Just wondering what they are about... Oh, yeah. Got an NVIDIA card.